# Vagrant status is "running" but VirtualBox shows "Powered Off"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I've successfully provisioned a base CentOS box, and can connect to the terminal via ssh.  Running "vagrant status" shows the virtualbox is running.  However, when I open the VirtualBox GUI the box shows "Powered Off".  I assume this has to do with the "headless" mode, but I'm wondering if I may be doing something wrong.  It seems that regardless of the state of a GUI for the box, the VirtualBox GUI should be reporting the same as vagrant.

Comment: It's possible that Vagrant and VirtualBox are out of sync, but I've not seen that before. Have you tried using the VirtualBox command line like `VBoxManage list vms` or `VBoxManage list runningvms`? Also are you sure this Vagrant is running inside VirtualBox (i.e. not another provider like VMware)?

Comment: I am seeing this too, and when I run `VBoxManage list runningvms`, it shows the VM that vagrant thinks is running, but the Virtual Box ui still shows it powered off.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem and it was solved by running VirtualBox as Administrator (on Windows 10) and it then showed the vagrant started vm as running.

Comment: That's it. Had the same problem but starting VirtualBox as Administrator did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in Windows 10 by running my Powershell window that I ran the Vagrant commands in as Administrator.  Once I did that, VirtualBox started showing the proper status even if it wasn't started as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Please Close your terminal and execute vagrant status again